# What's the difference between "to plug in", "to connect" and "to link"?

Tags: difference, word-difference, terminology

What's the difference between "to plug in", "to connect" and "to link"?

For example, what should I use when speaking about connection between program modules? And about network? etc.

Answer (score -4):

To use an analogy

> to plug in

is a car parking in a garage, the car becomes "enclosed" in the garage.

> to link
>   to connect

is a car driving over a bridge, the two sides of the bridge remain separate but joined.

Usually networks are *linked* or *connected* together, and you can *link to* or be *connected to* a network, but you can also *plug into* a network since as a user you will become a part of the network.

*Add-ons* or *plug-ins* (the literal usage) become part of a larger whole

> browser plug-ins

are additions to a browser's functionality.

A *link* or a *connection* can be broken, but a *plug-in* is *removed*.

A *plug-in* can also be *broken*, but that is in reference to its functionality as a plug-in, not the relationship of the plug-in with the browser.  Similarly, a *link* or *connection* can be removed, but that is referencing the link itself, not the its bridging functionality.

Comment: A car in a garage doesn't become part of the garage. It's just inside the garage. I don't "plug-in" to my house when I go inside it.

Comment: @Peter Is "plug in" in the context of a garage a dialectical usage? A translation from another language?

Comment: The analogy was not to be taken literally, it was to point out that the connection between either the garage or both sides of a bridge are different kinds of connections.  One can argue that a browser plug-in is not part of the browser but is "inside" the browser, however both car and "plug-in" are "enclosed".

Comment: A plug-in as a noun is different from the verb to plug-in though. I think I was reading the question a bit differently, but the car analogy is really confusing. With the garage the car is the thing "plugging in" but with the bridge, the bridge is the connection and the car is irrelevant. To me an electrical analogy would be better. Plugs go in sockets. Connections can be made by twisting wires together. Etc.